# eclipse web.xml jsp config

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

In an Eclipse JEE project with the Dynamic Web Module 3.0 facet enabled, I am developping a webapp fragment which consists in Java classes, JSP and other pages, which will then be deployed in a WAR. In this WAR's `web.xml` there's the following:

```xml
<jsp-config>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>/tags/struts-tiles</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-tiles.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
    [same for other taglibs, JSTL core etc.]
</jsp-config>
```

Which forces me to have at the beginning of my JSPs:

```
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
```

But then, how do I tell Eclipse to take this jsp config into account? Right now it simply looks in the classpath, finds into `standard.jar` and `struts.jar` the tlds and sees the `<uri>` is wrong (for struts-tiles for example it's `http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/tags-tiles` and not `/tags/struts-tiles`), and then the JSP parser `Can not find the tag library descriptor for...`.

If I paste the `web.xml` in my project's `WEB-INF` folder it seems to be ignored.

Comment: Okay so if the downvoter could explain him/herself...

Comment: Most of them just down-votes. I believe at least the effort of the asker/answerer should be respected at least to the point that if we have to down-vote their post, we explain the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using web fragments (deployment descriptor fragments), which allow you to write modular "chunks" of web.xml configuration which will then can be combined by the container during development to form the entire application.

Requirements :

1) Each fragment must reside in its own JAR (typically along side the classes being configured that make up the application) inside the **META-INF/web-fragment.xml file**. (at most one!)

2) The JAR file must be deployed to /WEB-INF/lib/ directory of the Web application.

Comment: Is this matching my usecase if I don't develop the whole WAR but just a small component of it to be manually added without any right to edit with the standard files such as web.xml?

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting your question.

Comment: My point is that I am not in charge of creating the entire application (i.e. the whole WAR). I just need to develop a component whose structure is specific to the host application. It's up to me to compile the right classes and copy the right pages where I need to, but I just want my JSP validator to work.